# Have same DIV display for different HTML Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, tabs

I have a set of 10 Search Fields to be displayed when 2 different tabs are clicked. Both the tabs have same set of 10 fields. Instead of having different DIV, I want to use same DIV and based on the specific TAB selection, I want to only change my AJAX REST End-Point.

Pls help how to use same DIV for different TABS in HTML.

1) HTML: Code below shows 2 tabs and the 2 DIVs - Entity and Claim. Want to use only 1 DIV as both ENTITY and CLAIM DIVs have same set of fields.

```
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" name="entity"
        onclick="openTab(event, 'entity')" id="defaultOpen">Entity
        Search</button>
    <button class="tablinks" name="claim" onclick="openTab(event, 'claim')">Claim
        Search</button>
</div>

<div id="entity1" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Entity</h3>
</div>

<div id="claim1" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Claim</h3>
</div>



<div id="entity" style="text-align: center" class="tabcontent">
    <form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" method="POST" align="center">

        <label align="center" class="h1"><font size=6><b>ER
                    Search Service</b></font></label> </br> </br> </br>

        <input type="hidden" id="userID" name="userID" value="">

        <script> 



        </script>

        <table align="center">

            <tr>
                <td>EntityID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="entityid" width=10></td>
                <!--                <td>ClaimID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="claimid" width=10></td> -->
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstname" width=10></td>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastname" width=10></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address Line 1</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="addrLine1" width=10></td>
                <td>Address Line 2</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="addrLine2" width=10></td>
                <td>City</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="city" width=10></td>
                <td>State</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="state" width=10></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Country</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="country" width=10></td>
                <td>Zipcode</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="zipcode" width=10></td>
                <td>SSN</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ssn" width=10></td>
                <td>DL Number</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="dl_num" width=10></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DOB</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="dob" width=10></td>
                <td>Professional License</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="profLic" width=10></td>
                <td>Policy Number</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="policyNum" width=10></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        </br>

        <table align="center" class="h1">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="simplepost" value="Search"
                    align="center"></td>
                <td><input type="reset" id="reset" value="Clear"
                    onClick="runReset()" align="center"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </br>
        <table align="center" class="h1">
            <tr>
                <td><select id="downloadFormat" align="center">
                        <option value="selectValue" selected>Select Download
                            Format</option>
                        <option value="csv">CSV</option>
                        <option value="xls">Excel</option>
                        <option value="xml">XML</option>
                        <option value="pdf">PDF</option>
                </select></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="download" value="Download"
                    disabled=true align="center"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</div>


<div id="claim" style="text-align: center" class="tabcontent">
    <form name="claimform" id="claimform" method="POST" align="center">

        <label align="center" class="h1"><font size=6><b>ER
                    Search Service</b></font></label> </br> </br> </br>

        <table align="center">

            <tr>
                <td>EntityID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="entityid" width=10></td>
                <td>ClaimID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="claimid" width=10></td>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstname" width=10></td>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastname" width=10></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address Line 1</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="addrLine1" width=10></td>
                <td>Address Line 2</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="addrLine2" width=10></td>
                <td>City</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="city" width=10></td>
                <td>State</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="state" width=10></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Country</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="country" width=10></td>
                <td>Zipcode</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="zipcode" width=10></td>
                <td>SSN</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ssn" width=10></td>
                <td>DL Number</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="dl_num" width=10></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DOB</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="dob" width=10></td>
                <td>Professional License</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="profLic" width=10></td>
                <td>Policy Number</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="policyNum" width=10></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        </br>

        <table align="center" class="h1">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="claimpost" value="Search"
                    align="center"></td>
                <td><input type="reset" id="reset" value="Clear"
                    onClick="runReset()" align="center"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </br>
        <table align="center" class="h1">
            <tr>
                <td><select id="downloadFormat" align="center">
                        <option value="selectValue" selected>Select Download
                            Format</option>
                        <option value="csv">CSV</option>
                        <option value="xls">Excel</option>
                        <option value="xml">XML</option>
                        <option value="pdf">PDF</option>
                </select></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="download" value="Download"
                    disabled=true align="center"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</div>
```

2) JavaScript:

```
<script>

var tabSelected = '';
var userID = getParameterByName("userID");
//alert(userID);

function setUserID() {
    //userID = getParameterByName("userID");
    document.getElementById("userID").value = userID;
    //alert(document.getElementById("userID").value);
}       

function getParameterByName(variable) {
      var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
      var vars = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
          return pair[1];
        }
      } 
      //alert('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');
} 


function openTab(evt, tabName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    } 
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

    if (tabName == "entity") {
        tabSelected = "getEntity";
        alert(tabSelected);
    } else if (tabName == "claim") {
        tabSelected = "getClaim";
        alert(tabSelected);         
    }

}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

</script>
```

3) AJAX:

```
$("#simplepost").click(function(e) {
    //getUsersAndDisplay();
    tabSelected = "getEntity";
    //alert(tabSelected);
    convertJSONToTable(tabSelected);

});
//GETUSERS Button ends

$("#claimpost").click(function(e) {
    tabSelected = "getClaim";
    //alert(tabSelected);
    convertJSONToTable(tabSelected);

});
```

AJAX REST-ENDPOINT CALL: Want to call same method based on the variable  which is getting the right values. But problem is how to display same DIV for different TAB Selections.

```
function convertJSONToTable(tab) {

    var MyFormData = $("#ajaxform").serializeJSON();
    console.log(MyFormData);
    var MyFormJSON = JSON.stringify(MyFormData,null, 2);
    console.log(MyFormJSON);

    var urlSelected = '';

    if (tab == "getEntity") {
        urlSelected = "http://localhost:8089/restserver/rest/getEntity";
    } else if (tab == "getClaim"){
        urlSelected = "http://localhost:8089/restserver/rest/getClaim";
    }


     $.ajax({
     url : urlSelected,

     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json",
     data : MyFormJSON,
     success: function(response) {

        //Store result in Session and Enable Download button
        response = removeAllBlankOrNull(response);
        var cacheString = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);
        console.log("-----------------> cacheString is: " + cacheString);

        var sessionresponse = sessionStorage.setItem("i98779", cacheString); 
        console.log("----------------------------------------------------------------");
        console.log("Response is: " + response);
        console.log("----------------------------------------------------------------");                        

        if(cacheString != null && cacheString != "[]") {
            document.getElementById("download").disabled = false;
        }
        createTable2(response);
     },

     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
     {
        console.log(errorThrown);
        alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
     }

     });

 }   //convertJSONToTable() Ends here
```

Comment: You could use two buttons in the same form. Each button runs a specific ajax request. Based on the selected tag one button is shown and the other one is hidden.

Comment: Could you be more specific where exactly you are referring to with respect to the buttons. Pls copy the specific code snippet from above, so that I can get what you are saying. Thank you. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one form and therefore only one "tab". But with two buttons you can let it appear like having two tabs. Each of these buttons shows/hide a submit-button in the form.

The form has to submit-buttons. One is sending the variable "claim" to the ajax-function. The other one is sending "entity" to the ajax-function.

HTML

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" name="entity" id="open-entity">Entity
    Search</button>
  <button class="tablinks" name="claim" id="open-claim">Claim
    Search</button>
</div>

<div>
  <form>
    <!--Input fields goes here-->

    <!--Two submit buttons in the same form, each is sending its individual   variable to your ajax function-->
    <input type="button" id="submit-entity" value="Download"
                disabled=true align="center">
    <input type="button" id="submit-claim" value="Download"
                disabled=true align="center"></td>
  </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
//Define which form should be shown on page-load, in this case "claim"
$('#submit-claim').show();
$('#submit-claim').hide();

//Show button to submit claim-form, hide button for entity-form
$('#open-claim').click(function(){
  $('#submit-claim').show();
  $('#submit-claim').hide();
});

//Hide button to submit claim-form, show button for entity-form
$('#open-entity').click(function(){
  $('#submit-entity').show();
  $('#submit-entity').hide();
});

//Call ajax if submit button is clicked
$('#submit-entity').click(function(){
  convertJSONToTable('entity');
});

$('#submit-claim').click(function(){
  convertJSONToTable('claim');
});
});
```

SECOND OPTION:

Instead of having two submit buttons you can add a hidden input-field to your form. If the user clicks on the `#open-claim` button the value of the input field is changed to 'claim'. If clicked on `open-entity`its value gets 'entity'.

```
$('#open-claim').click(function(){
  $('#form-type').val('claim');
});

$('#open-entity').click(function(){
  $('#form-type').val('entity');
});
```

Then, when clicked on the submit-button of the form the value of the input field is sent to the ajax-function.

```
$('#submit-btn').click(function(){
  convertJSONToTable($('#form-type').val());
});
```